# Is it possible to create a knot that is locked only when the rope is stretched?

Tags: mathematics, puzzle-creation, topology

Is it possible to create a knot that is stable/locked when the rope is stretched?
When the tension is relived the knot should open.

Comment: Would a [lariat loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E07rbIRybSo) suffice?

Comment: For two ropes tied together? Or a single rope? Seems like any knot in any single rope fits this if the rope material is smooth enough for it to happen in any one case - no rope knot is stable/locked without tension, just a tangled rope. Tension forms the knot initially and tension between the touching surfaces of the rope maintains it/keeps it stable. TL;DR; Please clarify, I'm confused

Comment: Would a Prusik Loop work? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prusik This needs two ropes though.

Comment: [Sheepshank](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Knots/Seizing_knots/Sheepshank)?

Comment: The mariners use the [bowline knot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline). It is easy to info it when it is not in tension.